# js to flask and back to js in a single page app

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax, flask

For my **single page** web app, I need to:

1. Send a json from .js to flask **(DONE)**
2. Run the input through a python function - getString()  and get a str output **(DONE)**
3. Send the str output back to the .js file **(PROBLEM)**

Here is the flask app:

```
@app.route('/',methods =['GET','POST'])
def index():
    req = json.dumps(request.get_json())

    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = getString(req) #Function outputs a string
        return jsonify(result)
    else:
        print('Not Received')

    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The problem is that the jsonify(result) is not being sent probably due to the request.method == 'POST' switching to else when jsonify is called. Is there any way to fix my code to send the str output to the .js?

Here is the .js:

```
//To send info to flask
document.querySelector('#generate').addEventListener('click',function() {
    var json_inputs = JSON.stringify(inputs);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url: "/",
        traditional: "true",
        data: json_inputs,
        dataType: "json"
        });

})

//To receive from Flask
$.ajax({
    url: "/",
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what GET and POST are, GET is a request that only fetches something from the back end without a message body but a POST can send a body and recieve something.

try this instead:

```
document.querySelector('#generate').addEventListener('click',function() {
    var json_inputs = JSON.stringify(inputs);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url: "/",
        traditional: "true",
        data: json_inputs,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

})
```